# Comparison of TeXworks editor with others with respect to spell checking

Tags: spelling

I use TeXworks editor on Windows where the default setting appears to be

a) Errors are underlined in red (but TeX code is not recognized and so it is underlined too; and ``comments'' are in red too) this makes for an egg hunt to find the errors.

b) You cannot permanently add a word to the dictionary

Can the default be changed and how do other editors perform in this respect?

Comment: In this site it is recommended to have *one* question per thread. I'd say that your question is somewhat overloaded - maybe you should try to split it into several isolated questions.

Comment: It is not an editor thing, but I would recommend UTF-8 input files. It improves readability as well as enables spell checking for many (non-english) texts. `Mit freundlichen Gr\"u\ss en` :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default dictionaries which probably pick-up the language from the locale are TeX aware.
Use Edit>Spelling>Your Language.

[image]

You cannot save new words, but you can install a new dictionary if you want and ignore warnings--as per the image above. There is a whole section in the manual how to install Libre Office dictionaries.

A better editor for Windows at a small figure is WinEdt 6.0. It has a better spell checker.

IMHO you chasing fleas in a haystack though. If you are to code extensively you will need to add all you PGF keys etc to the dictionary.

Comment: One can use a "magic line" at the beginning for setting the language on a document's basis: `% !TEXspellcheck =it_IT` will choose the dictionary with that suffix.

Comment: @egreg Sure there are a lot of directives. There is also a Comprehensive Help Manual.

Comment: Not really a lot; this one can be very handy for those writing in more than one language.